# How to use jQuery to make an input's changing value a php variable?

Tags: jquery, variables

Is it possible using jQuery, or any other language, to make an input's value a php variable without saving or refreshing the page?

I am trying to build a simple math form that has one constant and one variable. I need the calculated value to be displayed similar to the [Live Preview with jQuery](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/live-preview-with-jquery.html) script.

```
<input type="text" name="word" value="<?php $second_number ?>" />
<?php 
$first_number = 10;
$sum_total = $first_number + $second_number;
print ($sum_total); ?>
```

Live Preview with jQuery snippet, for reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() 
{
$(".word").keyup(function() 
{
var word=$(this).val();
$(".word_preview").html(word);
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not.

PHP is a *pre-processor*: its output is the HTML and Javascript that runs on your web browser. The PHP logic has *long gone* by the time it reaches the browser.

If you want to provide data to a PHP script and get data back out of it (for use on the web), you must do this through an HTTP request.

Make it an inline one (XmlHttpRequest or "AJAX") if you wish.

Comment: Thanks! I'll redirect my search for a jQuery math plugin and also look into an AJAX request...